# Can the Weierstrass M Test be used to find out where an Infinite Series Converges to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was under the impression that there was no analytic method to find out to what value an infinite series converges to - using methods like the ratio test one can find out if a series diverges or converges, but other than simulation/computational methods there is as such no analytic way to find out where an infinite series converges to. Can the Weierstrass M test be used to determine where an infinite series converges to? (from what I have read so far, it appears to be able to?)

Answer (score 0):

No, the M-Test can only give you an upper bound on the limit function.